# Dividing current between inverter and relay

Tags: relay, inverter, current-limiting, solar-energy, batteries

I want to make DIY ATS.

My power supply is from 120Ah 12V battery.

I have a 12V to 220 inverter and a relay circuit.

My problem is the inverter doesn't supply 220V when it is in parallel with the relay circuit.

The inverter is a 12V to 220V pure sine wave transformer.

I'm using an XH-M609 as a relay controller.

The XH-M609 will disconnect the voltage when the battery voltage is low.
The relay coil will be on when battery voltage is high, and will off when the battery is low.

Am I doing something wrong?

I think I need to limit the relay input current so inverter can gain more supply.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: What relay and what trafo (transformer)? A drawing of the setup will be most helpful. At the moment your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @DanielBudiono: Transformers don't convert DC to AC.  If yours is supposed to convert DC to AC, then it isn't a transformer.  "Trafo" is a commonly used expression for "transformer" in German, and maybe other languages.

Comment: Yeah, i search and it's called inverter. My mistake

Comment: The relay consists of a coil and a set of contacts. Where are the contacts? What type of relay? What type of inverter? We have no idea what these items are you refer to without you telling us.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. It's been fixed.
The problem is inside the inverter.
There's a cable not soldered properly